# $M$ a Hopf-module, is $M^*$ a Hopf comodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, hopf-algebras

Let $B$ be a finite-dimensional, commutative Hopf algebra over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and let $M$ be a $B$-module. Is there a natural way to view $M^*$ as a $B$-comodule (or, equivalently, as a $B^*$-module)? Here, $*$ stands for the $\mathbb{K}$-linear dual.